# How can I bigger block(bar) on ssrs graph reports?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2012, gantt-chart

I have gantt chart report on SSRS. I want to fix my order_id(PROD100059198) inside block(bar) that's why I need to bigger(wider) blocks(bars). 
How can I bigger these blocks?

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Select the Chart Series. In the Properties pane, navigate to CustomAttributes - PointWidth. Adjust to suit.
For a dynamic pointwidth

```
=IIF(CInt(CountDistinct(Fields!Prod.Value,"DataSet1"))< 3,0.2,0.5)
```

This would give you two sizes. You could extend the `IIF` to give many widths

Comment: yes I found this area but if I enter more than 1 pointwidht, my bars are overlap. I need to bigger bars and I need to protect gab between bars. Do you have any suggestion about that?

Comment: What did your report start at? Aim for somewhere between 0.8 and 0.9...